# Python Curses Replacement

Tags: linux, python, embedded-systems

I'm implementing a small application in Python that needs an interface, and a terminal application one would fit my usecase just fine. The target platform is a minimialistic Linux-based one that does not have the standard python curses module. I considered trying to bundle that with my application but the standard one requires some external .so files which makes it a problem for me, as the target Platform can be ran on different hardware with different instruction sets so this approach would require me to provide several compiled version of the .so files and also make it possible that my application will break in the future if it encounters a new platform.

So what good alternatves can one find for curses? My application needs to respond to both userinput but also events originating from the application itself and not the user.

Comment: Which facilities from curses do you need for your application?

Comment: Generally full screen applications, reading keys without waiting for the return key, hiding the cursor, writing at a specific x and y coordinate and basic text coloring.

Comment: What terminal types do you want to support?

Answer (score 1):

Text colouring and cursor placement can be obtained from [coloroma](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) using simple ANSI escape sequences but if you need keyboard event detection and more sophisticated screen handling your best bet is [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org)